# Best way to proxy all PostgreSQL database requests through a single server

Tags: postgresql, aws, azure, proxy

I am currently use AWS to host a number of EC2 instances and Container Services of which some connect to an RDS PostgreSQL database. We have recently been tasked to migrate all of our Database workloads to a Azure (with inbuilt pgbouncer). To effect this, we will need to update/modify all our connection strings in about 10-15 services which can be cumbersome.

Is there a way in which we can provision a single instance which we can use to redirect all database connections to the new database such that in the event that we need to change/update the connection strings again, we can just do it from one place?

I have come across [pgproxy](https://github.com/wgliang/pgproxy) but I am not sure if there is another way to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: You could probably do that with pgbouncer.  But then the next task would be, how do we get rid of the extraneous pgbouncer instance?  Or move it?  It seems like you really need some kind of centralized configuration setup.